# Blazor-Server sidenav/sidebar for Identity/Account/Manage that looks like NavMenu.razor

Tags: c#, user-interface, blazor, blazor-server-side

Default Blazor project is very inconsistent when it comes to UI. For blazor components, there is a sidenav. But for account manage /Identity/Account/Manage there is no sidenav as that is .cshtml not .razor page.
I know that to have consistent UI I have to have probably two side nav and maintain exactly the same layout for both of them. Still, maybe there is already some example of sidenav for /Identity/Account/Manage that looks exactly as that available for blazor components?

The most welcome solution is use existing blazor navbar (Shared/NavMenu.razor) in account management (/Identity/Account/Manage) pages

Comment: ...and a cshtml page can host a razor component, like say your Blazor menu

Comment: @MisterMagoo could you help me with that, assuming that my sidenav is 
Shared/NavMenu.razor should I add 
<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>
to: Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage\_Layout.cshtml ?

Comment: Adding that way <div class="sidebar">  @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<NavMenu>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
</div> dosn't work.

Comment: Take a look at the `component` tag helper : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/component-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a PR against your sample on GitHub. The change is to the  _Layout.cshtml used by Identity - it's not perfect, but shows the technique.

`_Layout.cshtml`

```html
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines
@inject IWebHostEnvironment Environment
@inject ICompositeViewEngine Engine
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - BlazorAuthTemplate</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Identity/css/site.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <app>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <component type="typeof(BlazorAuthTemplate.Shared.NavMenu)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
            <div class="d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                @{
                    var result = Engine.FindView(ViewContext, "_LoginPartial", isMainPage: false);
                }
                @if (result.Success)
                {
                    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_LoginPartial");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The default Identity UI layout requires a partial view '_LoginPartial' " +
                        "usually located at '/Pages/_LoginPartial' or at '/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial' to work. Based on your configuration " +
                        $"we have looked at it in the following locations: {System.Environment.NewLine}{string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, result.SearchedLocations)}.");
                }
            </div>
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>
        <main role="main" class="content px-4 pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
    </app>
    <script src="~/Identity/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Identity/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    <script src="/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```